# Dynamic Button Onclick Listener

Tags: android, button

I am trying to create dynamic buttons. When clicking a button it should go to the specified url assigned to the text of the button.

For testing, first I tried to get that ID, if it is equal it prints the value of `i`. But whenever I clicked any one button, instead of telling that particular `i` value, it enters into whole loop, and prints all the values of `i` starting from 1 to 19 (the number of buttons that are dynamically created)

And after printing all values from 1 to 19, the program is getting force closed saying `Null pointer exception`.

I even tried by placing the handler code outside `onCreate()`, but I'm still getting the same error.

```
for ( i = 0; i <itemList.getTitle().size()-1; i++) {
    title[i] = new TextView(this);
    title[i].setTextColor( -16711936 );
    title[i].setTextSize(18);
    title[i].setText("Title = "+itemList.getTitle().get(i));
    description[i] = new TextView(this);
    description[i].setTextColor(-16776961);
    description[i].setText("Description = "+itemList.getDescription().get(i)+"......");
    more[i]=new Button(this);
    more[i].setText(itemList.getLink().get(i));

    layout.addView(title[i]);
    System.out.println("Title view is set");
    layout.addView(description[i]);
    //System.out.println("Description view is set");
    layout.addView(more[i]);

    more[i].setOnClickListener(listener);
}

private OnClickListener listener=new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View arg) {
        int index = 0;  
        for (i = 0; i < more.length; i++)  
        {  
            if (more[i].getId() == arg.getId())  
            {  
                index = i;  
                System.out.println("Value of i onclick is"+i);  
            }  
        }
        //System.out.println("Vlaue of I in onclick"+i);
        //Uri uri=Uri.parse(itemList.getLink().get(i));
        //startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri));

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This button is clicked"+i+more[i].getText()+itemList.getLink().get(i),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setTag()` and `getTag()` method of View to identify different button.

```
for (i = 0; i < itemList.getTitle().size()-1; i++)  {
    ...
    more[i].setTag(i);  // Use index of itemList as the tag
}
```

In onClick:

```
int index = (Integer)arg.getTag();
```

Comment: Could you please help me in getting text of that button,since arg.settext is not working.Is there any other way,to get text of the clicked button

Answer (score 1):

you can also set the id of button

```
more[i].setid(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = 0;  
for (i = 0; i < more.length; i++)  
{  
   if (more[i].getId() == arg.getId())  
   {  
       index = i;  
       System.out.println("Value of i onclick is"+i);  
   }  
}
```

As you can see here, i is still in your for loop.
Put the `System.out.println("Value of i onclick is"+i);` outside of your for loop and it should work

PS: format your code, it's easier to read that way and you'll notice small mistakes like these more easily

Comment: Thanks.But it still says null pointer exception,without printing any i values

Comment: Could you update your post with the complete errorlog and the complete code?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you..

set button tag also dynamic like

```
more[i].setId(i);
```

and also changed condition like

```
 if (more[i].getId() == i) {
     index = i;
 }
```

hope this will help you...